# Symbolic integration of vectors in Sympy

Tags: python, vector, sympy

I wanted to know how to create symbolic vectors in sympy. Once I have accomplished that, I would like to understand if it possible to integrate the following type of complex equation using sympy platform. I want the analytical solutions and hence want the solutions in symbolic form.

x1,x2,B are all 3D vectors, c is a small positive constant and 
integrating w.r.t 't'

[image: eq1]

[image: eq2]

If this gets complicated in sympy could you please suggest any other platform to go forward with such analytical solutions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at sympy.vector (http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/index.html) and sympy.physics.vector (http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/vector/index.html). Maybe you will find something useful there.